# How do i select rows of table if value of a column is 0 else do left join if value is not 0 in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, left-join

I want to get values of few columns of 'table1' if value of 'test' column of table1 is 0 else do left join with 'table2' and select few columns of 'table2' in sql?

Both table have different number of columns with different names.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Do table1 and table2 have the same columns?  If not, then you are asking for two different queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.join_column,
       t1.anycase_column,
       CASE WHEN t2.join_column IS NULL
            THEN t1.case_column
            ELSE t2.case_column 
            END case_column
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.join_column = t2.join_column
                   AND t1.check_column != 0
```